1Hz pulse generator using 1ppm TCXO - schematic review
I am designing a PCBA intended to provide a 1Hz frequency with 1ppm accuracy.
I plan to use the SiTime SiT7910AI-1Q18-B32.768 model component and connect a binary counter to it.

Power input schematic

TCXO connections
components:

Do you have any suggestions for improving the circuit?

What improvements you are after? Also isn't that a 1.8V part and you are feeding 3.3V to it?

Why not use https://www.sitime.com/products/1-hz-4625-khz-oscillators/sit1569

What are your expectations for errors?  Environment? Power? startup time? cost? Tolerances? Size? Testability? MTBF? Phase noise [ns] Microphonics?

What is your test plan to verify 1 ppm under all conditions, does it need anything else to added to measure phase or frequency error? while testing -40 to +70C or whatever

Is there any condition in power cycling that can cause latchup when connected to load?

Your terminated 50 ohm output goes to a terminal block? You don't want to use 50 ohm coax to match the termination? A slightly smaller resistor value might be good too to account for the output impedance of the AHC in series with the resistor.

The part number is a 1.8V part as @Justme notes. There is a YY part that can work with a high voltage 3.3V supply, however it looks like the more stable 'Q' and 'P' parts are 1.8V only. And the aging (+/-1.3ppm typical for 1 year) is only specified for 1.8V supply. So better to add a little 1.8V SOT-23 voltage regulator (which will also help keep noise out of the oscillator, especially with a bit of filtering) and a voltage translator such as SN74AXC1T45.
I would suggest using an inexpensive low-capacitance TVS array designed for USB on the output, such as USBLC6-2P6. And maybe split the series resistor with the TVS in the middle. The one you show provides no protection for a negative voltage applied to the output.
A P-channel MOSFET might be a better reverse voltage protection than the diode.
Not sure what you're driving with the output so I'll not add to the comments in that respect.
74AHC1G4215 is a nice little chip, and marked 'active' with some stock showing,  at some suppliers, but it is single-sourced.
